# Clear the Excel cells format using VBA without clearing the NumberFormat

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to clear Excel cell format and content (using VBA) without altering the “`NumberFormat`” of the given cell.

I’ve tried with “`.ClearContents`” & “`.ClearFormats`”, but ClearFormats removed the *NumberFormat* of the cells too.

Please suggest.

Comment: clearing the format does **just that** clears the format. unfortunately there's no middle ground - meaning, only clear the `Bold` or the `Yellow Fill`.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim t
t = Range("A1").NumberFormat
Range("A1").ClearFormats
Range("A1").NumberFormat = t
```

It will save the number format then reapply it after clearing everything else.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a table?

    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, "AE8:AE10", , xlYes)
    Dim numfmt
    numfmt = tbl.Range.NumberFormat
    tbl.Range.ClearFormats
    tbl.Range.NumberFormat = numfmt  ' doesn't work
    tbl.Range.NumberFormat = "0.00%"  ' works
    Range("AE8:AE10").NumberFormat = "0.00%"  ' works

Comment: @ZaxR please do not use comments to ask a new question, instead post the question as a new post.

Comment: Already did, but figured I'd take a shot at getting you attn here. Here's my separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454038/vba-table-clearformat-except-numberformat . Thanks!